# How to turn a String into a nested Array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I get a String of the format
`<num-num-num><num-num-num><num-num-num>`. I want to turn this into a nested Array of Ints with each Array being the content between the `<>`.

This is what I got so far:

```java
String parameter = args[1];
// split the string into an array of strings at >

String[] splitString = parameter.split(">");
int[][] square = new int[splitString.length][splitString.length];

// remove <, > and - characters and push the numbers into the square

for (int i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++) {
    splitString[i] = splitString[i].replaceAll("[<>-]", "");

    for (int j = 0; j < splitString.length; j++) {
        square[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(splitString[i].substring(j, j + 1));
    }
}
```

I don't feel like this is very clean, but it works. Does anyone have an idea on how to improve readability?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Arrays

Comment: And since questions looking for "the best" "most neat" way to perform something are considered to be off-topic as opinionated, I kindly advise to change the phrasing.

Comment: I wouldn't care about "most elegant" but rather "working", "maintainable", "readable", "robust". "elegant" might imply "little code" whereas sometime a little more code makes a solution more robust and readable.

Comment: On the topic itself: is that string basically defining a 3x3 grid of numbers?

Comment: @Thomas It is defining a NxN grid of numbers.

Comment: It is a good idea to do units of work in separate methods so move this logic to a method and call that method.   e.g. `int[][] square = buildSquare(args[1]);`  One of the benefits of doing this is that it makes your code cleaner where the method is being invoked.

Comment: @vsfDawg Thanks. Already did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `"<num-num-num><num-num-num><num-num-num>"` would define a 3x3 grid so I would use the following approach:

- split the string into a string per row so we get `"num-num-num"`. That means:

  - remove the leading and trailing angular brackets
  - split at `"><"` and remove it
- split each row at `"-"` to get the individual numbers
- parse the numbers and assign them to the grid

Some code example:

```
String input = "<11-12-13><21-22-23><31-32-33>";
 
//remove leading < and trailing > then split at ><   
String[] inputRows = input.substring(1,input.length()-1).split("><");
    
int[][] grid = new int[inputRows.length][];
    
for( int r = 0; r < inputRows.length; r++) {
    //split the row at -
    String[] cells = inputRows[r].split("-");
        
    //convert the array of strings to an array of int by parsing each cell
    grid[r] = Arrays.stream(cells).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
}
```

Comment: Works great. And is much more readable. Thank you!

Comment: It can be done in a single statement ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74547085/17949945)).

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko true albeit I'm not sure this is more readable and maintainable. Of course it depends on the developers but sometimes splitting statements makes it easier to read and understand the code (if there's a noticable performance penalty then this changes matters). :)

Comment: I don't see an issue from the perspective of readability (this topic is subjective). But if it's not a `3x3` matrix, avoiding allocating intermediate an array might give a performance gain.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it can be done using Java 9 [`Matcher.results()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results()).

First, let's define a pattern that captures a group of digits interlaid with dashes `-`:

```
public static final Pattern ANGLE_BRACKETS = Pattern.compile("<([\\d-]*)>");
```

Using this pattern, we can create a matcher, and with `Matcher.results()` generate a stream of `MatchResult`s, which is an object representing the captured sequence of characters.

We can obtain the matching substring using [`MatchResult.group()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/MatchResult.html#group(int)) (`1` *should be passed as an argument, since we need a substring without brackets*).

To split each group, we can use either `Pattern.splitAsStream()` or `Arrays.split()`. In this case, the latter is preferred because splitting a string on dashes `"-"` can be done without compiling a regular expression and utilizing regex engine. `Pattern.splitAsStream()` might be more beneficial when array is large (`splitAsStream()` generates a stream directly from the regex engine with need to allocate an intermediate array), or we need to split a string using a regex, and not a regular string like `"-"`.

```
String parameter = "<1-2-3><4-5-6><7-8-9>";
    
int[][] matrix = ANGLE_BRACKETS1.matcher(parameter).results()
    .map(matchResult -> matchResult.group(1))
    .map(str -> Arrays.stream(str.split("-")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray())
    .toArray(int[][]::new);
    
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
```

*Output:*

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```